# How do i insert a value taken from text box (object) on a form into a 'LIKE' Query in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to build an update query in which once the user enters some text into a text box I have installed on a form, will then have a query (or perhaps loop) run so that all records in an underlying table which contain the value entered into the text box will be flagged.

At the moment my strategy is to take the value in the text box, paste it into a holding table (which I called tblSearchEngine07), and then run an my query which is aimed to identify all records where in the field called 'tblMasterListOfEventsNotes' the value pasted in my holding table will be referenced.  Unfortunately, I am having a syntax issue and am not successfully getting the holding table value to be correctly inserted into my query.

This is my current query syntax:

```
SELECT tblSearchEngine01.tblMasterListOfEventsNotes
FROM tblSearchEngine01, tblSearchEngine07
WHERE (((tblSearchEngine01.tblMasterListOfEventsNotes) Like "*[tblsearchengine07].[parolachiave]*"));
```

Comment: Can you please public your code? What do you mean by flagging your records? Can you public your table too?

Comment: Hi Kiks73. Im not sure if you were reading my old question prior to my edit which I made 5 mintues ago.  I re-wrote the entire question. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to substitute your like with this:

```
like "*" & tblsearchengine07.parolachiave & "*"
```

Update.

If you are not interested in storing your search values in a table, you can simply create your query string by reading textBox.value like this:

```
Dim sql as string
sql = "update yourtablename set yourfiled = true where yourconditionfield like '*" & textboxname.value & "*'"
Docmd.runsql sql
```

Comment: You got it..  Thanks so much.. I'm still not sure how this site works but is it possible for me to offer you some reputation points for your effort?

Comment: One quick followup/conceptual question if you don't mind. In your opinion, is my strategy for identifying these records the best or is there a better way? (for example: to not have to create that holding table to hold the textbox value)

Comment: If you don't need to store your search data, you can simply create your sql string reading directly your textBox.value. I try to explain it in my current answer

Comment: Kiks73, taking forward your solution and creating an SQL update query, i have the following but unfortunately i am getting an error message. Could you please have a quick look? I think it has something to do with the quotation marks.

Comment: st_sql = "UPDATE tblSearchEngine01, tblSearchEngine07 SET tblSearchEngine01.Query07ParolaChiaveSelect = '1' WHERE (((tblSearchEngine01.tblMasterListOfEventsNotes) Like " * " & [tblsearchengine07].[ParolaChiave] & " * "))"
    Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (st_sql)

Comment: @ Kiks73, i added a new question regarding the SQL query above to give the opportunity to answer another question. Thanks again for your help